# Cross browser AJAX and setTimeout() works in IE but fails in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, cross-browser, settimeout

Ok. This has been frustrating me for a few days now. I'm sure I'm an idiot and there is a solution right in front of my face but here's my question.

I have a series of AJAX calls that process and save data from a web page when the Save button is pressed. This has worked in IE for years (Was setup before I was hired) and have had no problems. We now have a requirement to support multiple browsers, namely IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

What I see when I try to press the save button in Firebug is that I get to the first AJAX call, I get the 200OK response and the time it took in ms, however it keeps spinning:

[image: Continues to spin forever]

The 17 seconds is because I stepped through the server side code.

The AJAX success handler method is never called and the whole thing falls apart. I have tried several different methods I've found searching but none of them seems to make much of a difference. <del>Here is the original code.</del>

EDIT 5:
Here is the updated code. I simplified it and took out the Step() method and all the timeouts. It's just the AJAX call that is causing the problem.

```
    function SubmitForm() {
        $.blockUI({ message: waitMessage, css: { padding: 5} });

        var settingsXml = GetSettingsXml();
        ajaxParameters = "customerId:'" + customerId + "', connectionId:" + connectionId + ", settingsXml:'" + settingsXml + "', securityToken:'" + securityToken + "'";

        AjaxCall("EmailMarketingSettings.aspx", "Validate", ajaxParameters, function (result) {
            alert("It works!")
        }, function (result) {
            alert("It's broken!");
        });
    }
```

`Validate()` will make it to the return statement but the code never returns to the client side success method.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Here is the requested AjaxCall method.

```
function AjaxCall(pageName, methodName, parameters, onSuccessCallback, onFailureCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageName + "/" + methodName,
        data: "{" + parameters + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 120000,
        success: function (resp) {
            result = resp.d;
            if (result.Success) {
                if (onSuccessCallback != null && typeof (onSuccessCallback) == "function") {
                    onSuccessCallback(result);
                } else {
                    $.unblockUI();
                }
            } else if (onFailureCallback != null && typeof (onFailureCallback) == "function") {
                onFailureCallback(result.Message);
            } else {
                alert(result.Message);
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        },
        error: function (req, errorType, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = "";
            if (errorType == "timeout") {
                errorMessage = "A timeout has occured"
            } else if (req.responseText.length > 0) {
                errorMessage = (req.responseText.substring(0, 1) == "{" ? eval("(" + req.responseText + ")").Message : req.responseText);
            } else {
                errorMessage = req.status;
            }
            if (onFailureCallback != null && typeof (onFailureCallback) == "function") {
                onFailureCallback(errorMessage);
            } else {
                alert("An error has occured: " + errorMessage);
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT 2: 
As soon as the request is sent I hit the error handler before my server side code returns anything at all. The AJAX call isn't waiting for anything to be returned it's just erroring out with an errorType of "error" and an empty string for errorThrown.

EDIT 3:
Raw data from Fiddler

FireFox:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 15:30:01 GMT
Content-Length: 178

{"d":{"__type":"CoreMotives.Web.MethodResult","Success":true,"Comments":"","Message":"","ElapsedMilliseconds":0,"SubTests":null,"NextStepAdditionalParameters":null,"Value":null}}

IE:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 15:29:53 GMT
Content-Length: 178

{"d":{"__type":"CoreMotives.Web.MethodResult","Success":true,"Comments":"","Message":"","ElapsedMilliseconds":0,"SubTests":null,"NextStepAdditionalParameters":null,"Value":null}}

Again though. The AJAX call hits the error handler before the server side code returns anything at all.

Edit 4:
Link to the .saz file from Fiddler.
http://tinyurl.com/ckmatsk

There should be only 2 entries in there.

Comment: So it's not so cross-browser, is it...?

Comment: Where is the AjaxCall function ? Are you doing synchronous aJAX ?

Comment: @dystroy I presume it is `AjaxCall(...)`?

Comment: What is the $.blockUI method ? Extended Jquery ?

Comment: Could you please show us `AjaxCall`?

Comment: Oh, woops. Missed the line. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: I added the AjaxCall method to the original post.

Comment: Block UI simply adds some "Please wait" functionality.
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI

Comment: I seem to be immediately hitting the error handler even before anything is returned by the server.

Comment: Is this failing on all the other browsers? have you compared the requests sent from IE and the other browsers? have you tried sending a request with, for instance, Fiddler?

Comment: @Gabobcat The request reaches the server however the client is not waiting for the response to come back and instead immediately erroring out with no information. It is failing on Chrome and FF but works in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... All this effort for something so stupid...

I figured out what my problem was thanks to this thread: [JQuery Ajax Firefox Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027079/jquery-ajax-firefox-error)

The SubmitForm() method was not returning false so the browsers default behavior was taking over. As soon as I changed the onclick to:

onclick="return SubmitForm();"

from:

onclick="SubmitForm();"

And made SubmitForm() return false. It started working in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks to anyone who was looking into it. Hopefully this helps someone in the future though I doubt there are many as dumb as me...